# AngularJS - how to add filesaver.js to meanjs library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

Am trying to implement [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) using meanjs. But it's not working.

Is it possible to use it with meanjs??

I have followed the below steps.

1- after installing filesaver file upload via bower with the command:

```
bower install file-saver --save
```

2- I have include reference to fileSaver.js files in my application layout page in the file: config\env\all.js like this:

```
assets: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'               
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
          'public/lib/file-saver/FileSaver.min.js',
                'public/lib/file-saver/FileSaver.js',
                ]
            },
```

3- then I included filesaver as a dependency in my angular application, in the file: public\config.js, by adding 'fileSaver' at the end of the array in this line:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'fileSaver'];
```

4- I am trying to export to an XL sheet using the following code from my meanjs client controller.

```
$scope.export = function($event) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTM], {
    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8'
});
saveAs(blob, 'Report.xls');
};
```

I am not able to use the file saver in my view. It warns saying 'saveAs' is not defined.

Thank you.

Comment: I would use pure javascript. Using MEAN doesn't mean (no pun intended) you have to go the Angular way. I'm no JS expert, but you can't just add a pure JS library and assume you can "import" it via dependency injection. I suggest you to build a service, put all the pure javascript in there, code in "pure" javascript (fileSaver JS library) and return the result of CRUD operations performed by fileSaver. Then you just wire your service via DI into your controller and voilà.

Answer (score 1):

I removed file saver from applicationModuleVendorDependencies  and it worked